# How to tell sed to make changes only to 1st column of an output

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, solaris

So i have an output with 6 columns, and what i want to do is ONLY for the first column to delete everything before the last semicolon " / ".
What i have so far is this

`df -k | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's@.*/@@'`

but i dont want to use the awk there in order to take only the first column like this, i want to find a way that i can tell to sed to make these changes to the first column only.

So the original output is like this:

```
Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/dsk/c0d0s0      12324895 5082804 7118843    42%    /
/devices                   0       0       0     0%    /devices
ctfs                       0       0       0     0%    /system/contract
proc                       0       0       0     0%    /proc
mnttab                     0       0       0     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                 8998420    1052 8997368     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                      0       0       0     0%    /system/object
sharefs                    0       0       0     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/usr/lib/libc/libc_hwcap1.so.1 12324895 5082804 7118843    42%    /lib/libc.so.1
fd                         0       0       0     0%    /dev/fd
/dev/dsk/c0d0s3      4136995  146364 3949262     4%    /var
swap                 9145604  148236 8997368     2%    /tmp
swap                 8997400      32 8997368     1%    /var/run
```

and i want the first column to look like this:

```
Filesystem
c0d0s0
devices
ctfs
proc
mnttab
swap
objfs
sharefs
libc_hwcap1.so.1
fd
c0d0s3
swap
swap
```

Comment: Why sed? Clearly you already know that awk is actually designed to work on columns (fields) so why would you want to use a different tool that isn't designed to work on columns?

Comment: because i searched on the man page and i couldnt find a method to do it in awk... any ideas on how to do in awk?

Comment: Of course, it's trivial in awk but you obviously couldn't find a method to do it in sed either or you wouldn't have asked the question so deciding it has to be in sed instead of awk when you didn't know how to do it in either tool seems very random.

Comment: lol, its not random man, i thought in start to do it in awk, i couldnt do it alone, so i thought to find something that is working, and then i said, oh hey, lets ask on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{sub(/.*\//,"",$1)}1' file
Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on
c0d0s0 12324895 5082804 7118843 42% /
devices 0 0 0 0% /devices
ctfs                       0       0       0     0%    /system/contract
proc                       0       0       0     0%    /proc
mnttab                     0       0       0     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                 8998420    1052 8997368     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                      0       0       0     0%    /system/object
sharefs                    0       0       0     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
libc_hwcap1.so.1 12324895 5082804 7118843 42% /lib/libc.so.1
fd                         0       0       0     0%    /dev/fd
c0d0s3 4136995 146364 3949262 4% /var
swap                 9145604  148236 8997368     2%    /tmp
swap                 8997400      32 8997368     1%    /var/run
```

.

```
$ awk 'NR==1{sub(/Mounted on/,"Mounted_on")} {sub(/.*\//,"",$1)}1' file | column -t
Filesystem        kbytes    used     avail    capacity  Mounted_on
c0d0s0            12324895  5082804  7118843  42%       /
devices           0         0        0        0%        /devices
ctfs              0         0        0        0%        /system/contract
proc              0         0        0        0%        /proc
mnttab            0         0        0        0%        /etc/mnttab
swap              8998420   1052     8997368  1%        /etc/svc/volatile
objfs             0         0        0        0%        /system/object
sharefs           0         0        0        0%        /etc/dfs/sharetab
libc_hwcap1.so.1  12324895  5082804  7118843  42%       /lib/libc.so.1
fd                0         0        0        0%        /dev/fd
c0d0s3            4136995   146364   3949262  4%        /var
swap              9145604   148236   8997368  2%        /tmp
swap              8997400   32       8997368  1%        /var/run
```

Comment: dude, seriously, you've got to stop with this blanket `it's not working for me` crap and provide some details. Does it produce incorrect output, no output, error message, core dump, something else? If an error message then copy/paste it along with the command you are running.

Comment: You said it before man, these things cant run on my machine because i am using old version of Solaris..... anyway, i get these errors:

`awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1`

run by this:

`df -k | awk '{sub(/.*\//,"",$1)}1' `

same on the second one as well..

Comment: I already told you twice to stop using old, broken awk and use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead.

Comment: Please enlighten me on how to do that, i am 3 weeks old in unix, thanks.

Comment: Instead of typing `awk <whatever>` type `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk <whatever>`. I highly recommend you read the books [Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson](http://www.amazon.com/Shell-Scripting-Recipes-Problem-Solution-Approach/dp/1590594711) and [Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033820.do) ASAP.

Comment: thanks a lot man, it works fine now.... so can i use this every time i use awk? or it can make me trouble with other stuff? also i checked the file its in, and i saw there is file for every command, if i use the same path on other commands as well its like i am running a better version of them??

Comment: Yes you can and check with your sys adming but in general yes, the commands in that directory will be more current than those in /bin. You can edit your `.profile` to set `PATH=/usr/xpg4/bin:$PATH` to pick up those commands before the `/bin` ones. I believe there may also be a newer version still in `/usr/xpg6/bin` but I'll leave the googling of that to you. The important thing is you must **never** use /bin/awk on Solaris as it is fundamentally broken.

Comment: btw in xpg4 are all the main command, and in xpg6 are just these,

`bc       dc       edit     expr     ls       tr       vi       xargs
crontab  ed       ex       getconf  stty     vedit    view
`

Answer (score 1):

Just split the first field in `/`-slices and replace the first field with the last of these slices whenever it occurs as the first part of the line:

```
awk '{n=split($1,a,"/"); gsub("^"$1,a[n])}1' file
```

#### Test

```
$ awk '{n=split($1,a,"/"); gsub("^"$1,a[n])}1' file
Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on
c0d0s0      12324895 5082804 7118843    42%    /
devices                   0       0       0     0%    /devices
ctfs                       0       0       0     0%    /system/contract
proc                       0       0       0     0%    /proc
mnttab                     0       0       0     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                 8998420    1052 8997368     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                      0       0       0     0%    /system/object
sharefs                    0       0       0     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
libc_hwcap1.so.1 12324895 5082804 7118843    42%    /lib/libc.so.1
fd                         0       0       0     0%    /dev/fd
c0d0s3      4136995  146364 3949262     4%    /var
swap                 9145604  148236 8997368     2%    /tmp
swap                 8997400      32 8997368     1%    /var/run
```

Note `awk '{n=split($1,a,"/"); $1=a[n]}1'` would also work, only that the format would be lost because the full string gets recalculated when you modify one of its fields.

Comment: just tried it, it doesnt work man, i get a error messages.

`awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1`

Comment: @SkatZ---IoannisSidiropoulos weird... It works fine in my GNU awk. Are you also using it?

Comment: @SkatZ---IoannisSidiropoulos you are using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris). It gives that error message for almost anything. On Solaris use `/usr/xpg4/big/awk`. `nawk` is also OK but isn't as close to POSIX.

Comment: @fedorqui the format is lost either way since you're shrinking the length of the first field.

Comment: @EdMorton OK. It doesn't get lost that much with `gsub()` though ;D

Comment: An yes, i am using Solaris. so no hope ha ?

Comment: Skatz - you should use the tag for the system you are actually using, not for some other system. It matters. I just told you which awk to use on Solaris, `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`. @fedorqui doing `gsub("^"$1,a[n])` should be avoided because it treats the first field from the input as a regexp and so it will fail if/when $1 contains regexp metacharacters. You also should be using `sub()` instead of `gsub()` in case the value of $1 appears again on the line. Use `sub(/^[^[:space:]]+/,a[n])` instead (thought that will still fail if/when `a[n]` contains a capture group reference of `&`).

Comment: thank you both @EdMorton & fedorqui every time you are very helpfull guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
df -k | awk '{print $1}' | perl -pe 's/^[\S]*\///g'
```

or

```
df -k | awk '{print $1}' |perl -lane '$F[0]=~s/.*\///g;print "@F"'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df -k|awk -F' ' '{print $1}'|sed "s/.*\///g"
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` solution

```
$ sed -r 's~.*/(\S+) ~\1~' file
```

or

```
$ sed -r 's~.*/(\S+)\s~\1~' file
```

Comment: Why `[^\S]` instead of `\s`?

Comment: I don't know how I typed this.  fixed now.